# kernel emulator i386 for kali linux for learning kernel development

Tags: linux, software-development, emulator

I would like to get started with **kernel development** and was told that I need a kernel emulator.

The problem is that I have only one system, and that is *Kali*.

How do I install a kernel emulator on Kali?

Comment: You probably want a better general desktop distro than Kali.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me